# how to interpret nouveau feature matrix

Tags: nvidia, nouveau

I have a GeForce G 105M. That's, I guess, an NV50 family video card:

https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/CodeNames/#NV50

My question is...  does [Nouveau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nouveau_(software)) support HDMI with this video card?

According to https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/FeatureMatrix/ TVout is "TODO" and HDMI audio is "DONE". What about HDMI video? Is that grouped under TVout or is TVout supposed to be [S-Video](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-Video) support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing HDMI video is basic enough that it's not listed in the feature matrix (along with other [supported display connectors](https://github.com/skeggsb/linux/blob/master/drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nouveau_connector.c) including VGA, single-link DVI, DisplayPort, LVDS...). If your NV50 card has HDMI connectors, they should be supported. (If you're looking for a mention in the documentation, HDMI support is hinted at in the [multi-monitor page](https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/MultiMonitorDesktop/).)